# using my own reduce function to check array intersection

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

I wanted to create a small application that could check arrays for intersecting values and reduce those arrays in a new one with only intersecting numbers. I was able to accomplish this using built in prototype methods but wanted to do it with my own defined functions.

```js
const forEach = (array, callback) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i])
  }
}
const reduce = (array, callback, initValue) => {
  accumulator = initValue
  const reduceFunction = (el) => {
    accumulator += callback(el)
  }
  forEach(array, reduceFunction)
  return accumulator
}
const intersectionWithReduce = (...arrays) => {
  currentValue = []
  reduce(arrays, el => currentValue += arrays.filter(currentValue.includes(el)), currentValue)
  return currentValue
}

console.log(intersectionWithReduce([1, 2, 3, 20], [15, 88, 1, 2, 7], [1, 10, 3, 2, 5, 20]));
// expected output of [1,2]
// actual output TypeError: false is not a function
```

Since `false` is being returned from currentValue I am throughly confused and will admit that recently the more I look at this the more I feel my solutions aren't making sense. What am I missing to make my reduce function work in this context.

Comment: `2` is not in the third argument array though? Why do you want to include it if it doesn't intersect?

Comment: i updated thank you

Comment: `currentValue.includes(el)` returns a boolean. You are passing it to `filter()`, which expects a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to emulate the functionality of `reduce`, call `callback` with (at least) two arguments: the current accumulator, and the current item being iterated over. Then assign the result to `accumulator`, and continue until the array is fully iterated over.

Because you want to find an intersection here, it would probably make the most sense *not* to pass an initial value - rather, take the first item of the array as the accumulator by default (just like `Array.prototype.reduce` does), and on each iteration, call `.filter` on the accumulator, testing against whether the other array contains the element:

```js
const reduce = (array, callback, initValue) => {
  let i = 0;
  let accumulator = initValue !== undefined ? initValue : (i++, array[0]);
  for (; i < array.length; i++) {
    accumulator = callback(accumulator, array[i]);
  }
  return accumulator;
}
const intersectionWithReduce = (...arrays) => {
  return reduce(arrays, (accum, arr) => accum.filter(accumItem => arr.includes(accumItem)));
}

console.log(intersectionWithReduce([1, 2, 3, 20], [15, 88, 1, 2, 7], [1, 10, 3, 2, 5, 20]));
```

Comment: so `accum` is the accumulator value and `arr` is the value of the other array, what other array is that? is it the next array that is located inside the running of `intersectionWithReduce` ?

Comment: `arr` is the current subarray being iterated over - eg, `[1, 2, 3, 20]`,or `[15, 88, 1, 2, 7]`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this simple approach without the need of using reduce though.

Look:

```
const intersectionWithReduce = (...arrays) => (
  arrays.map(arrElm => // array of arrays, arrays[0] = [1, 2, 3, 20]
    arrElm.filter(arrElm => // filtering for equals
      arrays.every(elm => 
        elm.includes(arrElm) // only evaluate if this item is present in every other array
      )
    )
  )[0] 
)
/*  /\
 * Here it's [0] because doesn't matter the position, 
 * all the remaining arrays will be the same. 
 * In this case without this part the result would be [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
*/

console.log(intersectionWithReduce([1, 2, 3, 20], [15, 88, 1, 2, 7], [1, 10, 3, 2, 5, 20]))
// output [1, 2]
```